# How to create an interactive filter where the user's choices are appended or removed in the input div itself

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, tailwind-css

Ok let me explain, Remember while asking questions in stack overflow at the end we need to choose 5 Topics related to our questions. Where we select individual topics/Tags and they append over that input div where we can even edit those Tags.

I tried looking for a particular **name** for such kinds of interactive mechanism. Because I am trying to implement the same approach for multiple files uploading feature where selected file-name is depicted the same way an individual tag is depicted in the stack overflow questioning section

Sort of like this
[image]
Also I am using Tailwind css for styling but honestly any approach is fine until i get a hold of what it is.

Comment: do you have tried mat-chips ? look these examples https://material.angular.io/components/chips/examples

Comment: Maybe the "name" of what you're trying to do is *a component for adding and removing editable chips*. In order to help you, we need the code you already have (if any), because, by now, this is a do-it-for-me question.